# Whatever became of d'Espagnet's library?

Tags: ho.history-overview

The library at Bordeaux where Pierre de Fermat learned enough mathematics by his predecessors to develop his technique of [adequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) was owned by Jean d'Espagnet who passed it on to his son Etienne d'Espagnet.  Etienne apparently eventually moved to Toulouse.  Whatever became of the library?  Did it follow d'Espagnet to Toulouse? Was it sold at an auction?  Did it become part of one of the national libraries in France?

A related question was asked at [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6421/did-kepler-influence-fermat) without success.

Comment: at least [one book](http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/PR-MONTAIGNE-00001-00004-00004/9) from Espagnet's library is now in the Cambridge University Library

Comment: Amazing find. @Carlo